# Git: exclude committed file from pull request

Tags: git, pull-request

I have a repo to which I have pushed my stuff. I have realized that I am pushing the `.idea/workspace.xml`, which I should have ignored (lot of useless configuration stuff).

Now it is on my remote repo, and I need to do a pull request.
Can the offending file be excluded from the pull request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you can not send pull-request with commit which removes `.idea/workspace.xml` because it's up to repository owner whether to merge that pull request or not.

So you need to modify the same commit where you've added that file.
To do that use `git rebase --interactive` Get SHA of the commit which is just before your wrong commit For ex. `ba0202e` . Then do following:

```
$ git rebase --interactive ba0202e
```

Then it will open an editor where it will list all the commits.
Just Find your wrong commit, and replace `pick` with `edit`.
Save the file and close it.

Now remove the file `.idea/workspace.xml`

```
$ git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml
```

It'll remove it from git but not from your local system.

Then amend the commit:

```
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --continue
```

Now you have to do force push the commits with option `-f` (It's bad practice but in your case there is no any other option.)